# Cannot read property id ember routes

Tags: javascript, ember.js

So this is my problem, I've created a route for searches, so far creating a new search is working I can submit and it will send a rest request to the backend and so on and that works.

now when I try and display one I saved I get this error

```
Assertion failed: Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

and I can't go any further it won't render the page (I know on the gist there is no render but I commented it out to see if that was the issue and it's not I still get the error)

The JSON that I get back from the backend is correctly configured as well as I can see it on the ember inspector, I tried even having the backend return all the searches and the ember inspector stores the lot of them, I just still get the same error, this is a link to the gist.

https://gist.github.com/mmarignoli/8002088

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
return this.store.find('Search', params.search_id);
```

with

```
return this.store.find('search', params.search_id);
```

Note the lowercase "s" in search

Also, replace:

```
{"Searches": [{"id": 11, "name": "adwadwd"}]}
```

with:

```
{"searches": [{"id": 11, "name": "adwadwd"}]}
```

Also lowercase "s" in the route names:

```
this.resource('search.new', {path:'/search/new'});
this.resource('search', {path: '/search/:search_id'})
```

Also, you are asking the server for an object, but you are returning an array.

Full code:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('search.new', {path:'/search/new'});
    this.resource('search', {path: '/search/:search_id'})
});

App.SearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function( params ) {
        return this.store.find('search', params.search_id);
    },
});
```

JSON:

```
{"search": {"id": 11, "name": "adwadwd"}}
```